# Make close/reopen privilege on own questions more prominent

Tags: feature-request, privileges

I've been a member for 9 months now, but I found out today (or had already forgotten) that you can vote to close, reopen or migrate your own questions with just 250 rep.

That might be just blindness on my part, but another possible reason is that this information is buried in the **How do I view close votes and reasons?** paragraph of the [view close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege.

I think we should make this information more prominent, since the ability to *cast* close/reopen votes is at least as important as the ability to *view* them. This could be achieved in a number of ways.

A few suggestions:

- Rename the privilege to **view and cast close votes**.
- Add a separate paragraph called **How do I close or reopen my own question?**

Comment: A moderator flag is more effective; you still need four more votes from other users to pull the trigger, which can be unlikely if your question has already dropped off the front page.  For maximum satisfaction on migrations, just delete your question and ask it on the proper site.

Comment: I completely agree that voting to reopen *any* question is futile in 9 out of 10 cases. The ability to cast close votes might be more interesting. Either way: If it's possible, there should be awareness.

Comment: I agree renaming it 'view and cast close votes' would be better. They have a lot of features so it's understandable, but it would be nice if it was more obvious. Personally I hate that to view privileges I have to type the url myself or go to FAQ and find link there.